vim does not write file without showing error
vim is unable to write to a file, it just shows '<filename>' 1L, 0C when writing.
I have tried :w, :wq, and :w! with the same result. The file is created (if it did not exist), but no contents are written to the disk.
I can only exit vim with :q! because of the ususal "No write since last change (:q! overrides)" message.

You didn't write the error message, but possibly I would write a bug report to vim, so that error message may be more helpful in case of failure: System will tell vim if it is an I/O error, a disk full, read-only (but i think that case is shown in vim), etc.

My disk was full. With no available disk space, vim can only write 0 bytes, i.e., nothing, to the disk and thus will always have unsaved changes.
After deleting another file to free up some space, everything works again.
